# What is the font size of a footer and header in photoshop?

Tags: tags, photoshop

I am designing a mockup in photoshop.

i know that i 1em is the same as 12 points used in photoshop.

When I have reseached what the font size is for nav and footer etc it comes up with H1 to H6.

Does anyone know the typical font size of headers and footers across all 3 devices (mobile, desktop and tablet)

Comment: There are no 'typical' font sizes. It depends entirely on what the designs are. In designing a mockup you're the one who decides the font sizes so that it looks 'good'. There are a number of standards such as with Bootstrap, but these are modified in themselves to match the designs.

Comment: Also this question has _nothing_ to do with programming at all. It's all about design

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I think the question is fair since the OP seems to be trying to understand how their designs will translate into web when handed over to a developer. So they can understand better how to design for web. Makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so h1 is a heading tag its looks big.

## This is a `h1` TAG

### This is a `h2` TAG

#### This is a `h3` TAG

None of which you should be using in your navigation. And note that you should ever only have one `<h1>` tag on any given page because that is how google determines and displays that pages content and you don't want to confuse google.

Most navigation's consist of an un-ordered list. Consisting of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.

For example your navigation may look something like this in html.

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li> home </li>
<li> about </li>
<li> blog </li>
<li> contact </li>
</ul>
```

And you would control the font-size via css and target only the li tags inside the navigation.

```
.navigation li{ font-size: 12px }
```

This is how it works on the development end.

When designing for a website in Photoshop. The pixel values used in web will display the same as they do in Photoshop if the current document you are working in has its resolution set to 72. (Which is standard web resolution)

Using `em` is fine. Using `em` gives the ability for the text to adapt to the available space. But using em in Photoshop is pretty pointless if you are not the one who is going to be coding the website. You can leave those decisions for responsiveness to your developer and consult with him on how you want it to appear on different screen sizes.

Please learn basic HTML and CSS before trying to design a website. 
Get started at https://www.w3schools.com/html/ and feel free to come back with your development questions.

Good luck.